# Spring data MongoDB condition in projection

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

How can I add condition on my projection stage during aggregation using Spring Data?

For example I want to add `new_field` that will be calculated by formula `field1 / field2`. From Code side it would look like:

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project("field1", "field2").andExpression("field1 / field2").as("field3");
```

But if `field2` is equal to `0`, I'll get an error. So to avoid such situation it was suggested to use `$cond` operator but I have no idea how it should look like in code. Do anybody have any thoughts?

Note. Expression `field2 != 0 ? 1 : 0` didn't work (even if "SpEL" allows such syntax).

Comment: I am wondering, if it is so difficult, that nobody have answered yet. I need to do the same

Answer (score 2):

It's a little late but for future viewers of this question, the following code worked for me. It returns 0 as the value of field3 when field2 is 0.

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("field1, field2")
                .and(AggregationSpELExpression.expressionOf("cond(field2 == 0, 0, field1/field2)"))
                .as("field3");
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue.
!= does not seem to be supported, however you can use "ifNull" or "cond" in your SPeL.

See here:
[how to use spel to represent $cond of mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613542/how-to-use-spel-to-represent-cond-of-mongo?noredirect=1&lq=1)

And here for more examples:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/SpelExpressionTransformerUnitTests.java

Answer (score 0):

You can find more examples here: https://www.javatips.net/api/spring-data-mongodb-master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ProjectionOperationUnitTests.java