# how to use spel to represent $cond of mongo

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-el

I have a collection with documents like below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5946360fdab24b1d05fac7e6"),
    "name" : "aaa",
    "createdAt" : NumberLong("1497773583563"),
    "segmentedStatus" : 0
}
```

I want to stat how many documents with segmentedStatus = 1,

```
db.foo.aggregate(
    {$project: {_id:0, segmentedCount:{$cond: [{$eq:["$segmentedStatus",1]}, 1, 0]} } },
    {$group: {_id:null, count:{$sum:"$segmentedCount"}}}
)
```

In spring data mongo

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(project().and("segmentedCount").applyCondition(when(where("segmentedStatus").is(1)).then(1).otherwise(0)),
        group().sum("segmentedCount").as("count")
);
```

but I feel above manner a little cumbersome  so want to know if could use spel in this case , I tried below manner

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(project().andExpression("segmentedStatus == 1 ? 1 : 0").as("segmentedCount"),
        group().sum("segmentedCount").as("count")
);
```

but it throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Element: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.spel.ExpressionNode@4d5d943d Type: class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.spel.ExpressionNode You probably have a syntax error in your SpEL expression!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use $cond operation in Spring-MongoDb aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186185/how-to-use-cond-operation-in-spring-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short hand ternary operator syntax for `$cond` is currently not supported. Still you can reference the `$cond` operator via `cond(if, then, else)`

```java
project()
  .and(AggregationSpELExpression.expressionOf("cond(segmentedStatus == 1, 1, 0)"))
  .grou...
```

which will create the following:

```
{ "$cond" : { "if" : { "$eq" : ["$segmentedStatus", 1] }, "then" : 1, "else" : 0 } }
```

Comment: ty for answer, i have a problem. how can i define a date in spel? like ->

`{ "$cond" : { "if" : { "$eq" : ["$segmentedStatus", 1] }, "then" : new Date(01-01-2019), "else" : 0 } }`